# A console application used to capture data and save it to a text file...How does one do it?

Tags: c#-3.0

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace ABC
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string userInput;
            List<string> a = new List<string>();


            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine(">>> NAME <<<");
                Console.WriteLine("1 - Add");
                Console.WriteLine("0 - Exit");

                //get user's choice/input
                userInput = Console.ReadLine();

                //actions to take after user's choice/input
                switch (userInput)
                {
                    case "1":
                        //Add list to store info
                        Console.WriteLine("B");

                        //capture details
                        a.Add("Name: ");
                        a.Add("Surname: ");
                        a.Add("Address: ");
                        a.Add("Telephone: ");
                        a.Add("Cell: ");
                        a.Add("Email: ");
                        a.Add("Web: ");
                        a.Add("Date: ");

                        foreach (string i in a)
                        {
                            Console.Write(i);
                            Console.ReadLine();
                        }
                        FileStream fs = new FileStream("myfile.txt",FileMode.Create,FileAccess.ReadWrite);
                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                        foreach (string str in a)
                            {
                            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader();
                            {
                                sb.AppendLine(str.ToString());
                                sb.Append(sr.ReadToEnd());
                                sb.AppendLine();
                            }
                        }
                        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"myfile.txt");
                        sw.Write(sb.ToString());

                        break;
                    case "0":
                        Console.WriteLine("BYE!!!");
                        break;
                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("{0} is not a valid choice", userInput);
                        break;
                }
                //allow user to see results
                Console.Write("press 'Enter' to continue...");
                Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            // Keep going until the user wants to quit 
            while (userInput != "0");
        }
    }     
 }
```

Comment: So what seems to be the issue?

Comment: What is the problem? Always when asking questions, dont forget to specify what did happen, what you think was supposed to happen and what steps you have already taken (that failed) to solve it.

Comment: I want to save user input to a text file.After compilation,the text file that I want to write to and also save to is created but it's empty...

Hope it's clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

I did not run your code, but:

a) don't forget to `close` your file.

b) it looks like you always add those "data fields" to you list (do it once, on clear it every time you add a new set)

Comment: And dispose of the FileStream and StreamWriter.

Comment: Or use `using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"myfile.txt") { sw.Write(sb.ToString()); }` ... IMHO, it is the better option.

Comment: I tried your approach,the text file is created but it's empty.

Answer (score 0):

You got a `FileStream` and a `StreamWriter` open on the same file at the same time, this will lead to an error.

Deleting the line

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream("myfile.txt",FileMode.Create,FileAccess.ReadWrite);
```

and relplacing

```
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"myfile.txt");
sw.Write(sb.ToString());
```

with

```
using (TextWriter tw = File.CreateTex("myfile.txt")) {
    tw.Write(sb.ToString());
}
```

should do the trick.

**Edit:** Your program is doing exactly what you told it to do.

So here is the functionality that I **think** that you want to achieve:

case "1":
    //Add list to store info
    Console.WriteLine("B");

```
//capture details
a.Add("Name: ");
a.Add("Surname: ");
a.Add("Address: ");
a.Add("Telephone: ");
a.Add("Cell: ");
a.Add("Email: ");
a.Add("Web: ");
a.Add("Date: ");

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (string i in a)
{
    Console.Write(i);
    var entry = Console.ReadLine();
    sb.AppendFormat("{0}{1}\n", i, entry);
}

using (TextWriter tw = File.AppendTex("myfile.txt")) {
    tw.Write(sb.ToString()); 
    tw.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------------");
}

break;
```

Comment: I've jst tried to append all data to a StringBuilder and used a StreamWriter to write to the file and StreamReader for reading.The file is created but instead of displaying data fields and user input,it displays data fields only.

Comment: Ok then Ob...how do I save user input to a text file?

Comment: @user: The text writer does this ... ??? I modified the code above to reflect that multiple entries have to be saved and added a separator between the entries ... but this is it really.

Comment: Ob...u such a beauty...thanx..:-)